# (Vis.js Network) Load nodes from database

Tags: json, dot, vis.js, gephi, visnetwork

I have a hard time understanding how to use vis.js network with a large amount of data generated dynamically. From what I read in the documentation, there are only two easy ways to import data: from gephi or in dot language; right? Isn't that a bit restrictive?

I have no knowledge of gephi or dot language so I decided to use my mysql database which I am used to working with. 
So I query my data with php, and generate javascript to build the nodes and edges for the network.

But so far, I only have about 200 nodes and edges (which is like 1/5 of the data I'll have in the end) and it's already very slow to load, it seems like it takes a lot of ressources to display the network (my MacBook Pro gets really loud anytime I open the network page), when vis.js is supposed to be quick and lightweight.

Is that because all the nodes and edges are "written" in the code of the page? Or is it the fact that I use php to query the mysql data?

I don't refuse the idea to work with a json file, or dot language, I just have no idea how to do that... but if it can get me better performances, I'd like to learn how to do it. Can anyone explain in details how it all works? And with either of these methods, can I get different sizes and colors for the nodes and the edges according to the data I need to show (right now I do that in php after querying the data from the database)?

Answer (score 1):

The format required by Vis Network can be serialized and deserialized using `const object = JSON.parse(string);` and `const string = JSON.stringify(object);`. There's no need to use Gephi or DOT to simply store data in the data base.

Nodes have `size` property to change size and both nodes and edges have `color` to change color. Edges can also inherit color from connected nodes. For more details see the docs for nodes at https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/nodes.html and edges at https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/edges.html.

Regarding performance there is not much I can tell you without some sample code and data to play with. I tried putting more that 200 nodes to https://thomaash.github.io/me/#/canvas which was built with Vis Network. As I expected it loads instantly and works just fine but I have no idea how fast or slow is MacBook Pro compared to my machine.